# Assigning a tag to multiple controls, of a given type, at once

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a database in Microsoft Access that I've designed a front-end for. There are approximately 35 forms/subforms so there are hundreds of controls. I have an audit structure for the entire front-end, but it requires adding a tag to each textbox control.

Is there an easy way to do this? Otherwise it'll be extremely manual, tedious and time consuming. I'd much rather write a bit of code that will automate the process of setting the tag for all of the textbox controls.

Comment: The tag is only a string like "tag_name" for all controls?

Comment: Code could cycle through Forms collection, open in design view, cycle through Controls collection, set the Tag property, close and save form. Would you want to set Tag for ALL controls (labels, subforms, lines, etc)? When you develop code that has issue, post a question. Whether or not this will be just 'a bit of code' and easier depends on your programming skills. A third-party tool like Rick Fisher's Find and Replace might be able to accomplish. Cost about $35.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in a single form:

```
Public Sub AssignTag()
    Dim control As Variant
    For Each control In Me.Controls
        If control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            control.Tag = "MyTag"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you have to open the form in layout view, change something, save the form, and possibly change the thing back, to make the change stick (changing controls using VBA doesn't persist unless you make an additional change in layout view).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `AllForms`, open each `Form` in design mode, set tag to all `TextBox` controls, save and exit.

```
Public Sub SetControlsTag()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim obj As AccessObject, frm As Form, ctl As Control

    For Each obj In CurrentProject.AllForms

        'Open in design mode
        DoCmd.OpenForm CurrentProject.AllForms(obj.Name).Name, acDesign
        Set frm = Forms(obj.Name)

        'Set tags
        For Each ctl In frm.Controls
            If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then ctl.Tag = "Whatever..."
        Next ctl

        'Close
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name, acSaveYes
        Set frm = Nothing
    Next obj

Leave:
    Set frm = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```